# Basic analytics for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, analytics

I am looking for a very simple approach for handling basic analytics in a rails app. Metrics I will like to obtain are page views and click rate. Any ideas how to go about this ?

Comment: Google analytics should offer everything you need, and is as simple as pasting a snippet. Is there a reason that won't suffice?

Comment: I just want something to record page views so i can also display it on a page. GA is just a little too robust but an excellent solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Errplane](https://errplane.com/) is an insanely-great product.

But it sounds like you want to roll your own.  As an answer to your question, I offer that this **is the wrong strategy**.

If you dislike that approach, probably best to just steal from NewRelic, since that's what they wrote their code to do.

Comment: Errplane is looking quite helpful. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @joshua glad to hear. I've met these guys at conferences, and I think their product is next-gen

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of helpful solution for analytics of your Rails application. 
The problem is what would you choose the one.

I thinks [this link](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html) is most latest and helpful document. 
I wish you to good choice. BTW, I'm using Google Analytics for metrics of my service.

Comment: Yes indeed Daniel does a good Job explaining some alternatives. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is still Google Analytics, there are others approach but they are more complicated to install/maintain. More, with GA, you can track from your mobile to your web applications. Easy & multi-platform :)

If you don't care about all the other metrics provided by GA, it's up to you to configure your own simple GA dashboard :)

"Qui peut le plus, peut le moins" :)

Comment: why have less indeed. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

my personal suggestion is to go with http://get.gaug.es/
I think is much simpler than Google Analytics yet very very powerful.

PROs
simple views
you can manage lots of sites without clicking all over the place like GA
develop by github
7 days free trail

CONs
you have pay for it.

ps: prices start @ $6.00
I used it is totally worth it.